# How to create wordpress user from cross domain registration form

Tags: wordpress

I want to create registration form for my website but my server is not provide database for storing data. so in this way i used wordpress on another server
and i want to store registration information in wordpress user information and maintain also with wordpress.
hows this possible....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is just overkill for your purpose. If your only problem is that your hosting provider is not giving you a database server, you should check out [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).